# How do I configure a variant to run both prod & debug app on same Android?

Tags: android, gradle

I added the following to my build.gradle:

```
def applicationId() { "com.rithmio.coach" }
def applicationName() { "Coach Rithmio" }

defaultConfig {
    applicationId applicationId()
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode gitVersion()
    versionName "${versionMajor()}.${versionMinor()}.${versionPatch()}"
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Coach (Debug)"

        final CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "${applicationId()}${applicationIdSuffix}.content"
        resValue "string", "content_authority", CONTENT_AUTHORITY

        final ACCOUNT_TYPE = "${applicationId()}${applicationIdSuffix}.account"
        resValue "string", "account_type", ACCOUNT_TYPE

    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        resValue "string", "app_name", "${applicationName()}"

        final CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "${applicationId()}.content"
        resValue "string", "content_authority", CONTENT_AUTHORITY

        // If you're plugging into the account auth system
        final ACCOUNT_TYPE = "${applicationId()}.account"
        resValue "string", "account_type", ACCOUNT_TYPE
    }
}
```

But this breaks my application in debug mode, all of the sudden the root classes are not where they are supposed to be.

It's looking for a class com.rithmio.coach.debug.mobile.* but it should be looking for com.rithmio.coach.mobile.*

How would i save modify this to look in the correct package?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
find class "com.rithmio.coach.debug.mobile.ScrollAwareFabBehavior" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rithmio.coach.debug-1/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rithmio.coach.debug-1/lib/arm,
/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I basically want to change the applicationid without changing the package name.

Comment: did you define <manifest package="..."/> in AndroidManifest? All classes should looking from that package, not applicationId from build.gradle

Comment: Yes, I did specify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How define product flavors in the build file :-

**To define two product flavors, edit the build file for the app module to add the following configuration:-**

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs { ... }
    buildTypes { ... }
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.demo"
            versionName "1.0-demo"
        }
        full {
            applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.full"
            versionName "1.0-full"
        }
    }
}
...
```

The product flavor definitions support the same properties as the defaultConfig element. The base configuration for all flavors is specified in defaultConfig, and each flavor overrides any default values. The build file above uses the applicationId property to assign a different package name to each flavor: since each flavor definition creates a different app, they each need a distinct package name.

More detailed answer here  :-

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to use the debug and release options, as I have to also configure content providers, and authenticators. I'm curious why applicationsuffixid doesn't create a package correctly?

Comment: i think applicationsuffixid is not same as package name in androi, have a read here and tell me  if it fits your doubt http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: This post makes sense, the package and applicationId are two separate things.  So i dont understand why my applicationId is affecting the classpath names...very strange